# Rails 3.2 - How Rails blank? method works internally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how Rails handles the method blank?.

I was trying to build my own blank? equivalent method but it's not easy. Here's my try:

```
def my_blank(state)
  if state == nil or state.empty? == true
     true
  else
     false
  end

end
```

Comment: Go to http://api.rubyonrails.org/, type "blank?", find the `blank?` you're looking for, and hit the corresponding "show" or "on GitHub" link. There are different `blank?` implementations patched into different classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This project is open source, so just take a look at the source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb

You'll see that there are individual methods written for the various classes (like `String`, `Array`, etc.)

Comment: As you can read from the source, the blank? method is a Rails specific monkey patch on each of the basic classes of Ruby: Object, NilClass, FalseClass, TrueClass, Array, Hash, String and Numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variant I wrote to help me with some of the structures in our system:

```
Object.class_eval do
  def deep_blank?
    self.kind_of?(Enumerable) ? self.inject(true) { |running, element| running &&= element.kind_of?(Enumerable) ? element.deep_blank? : element.blank? } : self.blank?
  end
end
```

Hope it helps someone.